# Symfony annotation routes do not match

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Hi guys I have a problem with some routes. I have a building which has floors and the floors have apartments. So I have build the routes about the apartments with listing by the object building and floor.

```
<?php

namespace George\ApartmentBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use George\ApartmentBundle\Entity\Apartment;
use George\ApartmentBundle\Form\ApartmentType;

/**
 * Apartment controller.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/apartment")
 */
class ApartmentController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Apartment entities.
 *
 * @Route("/{object}/{floor}", name="admin_apartment")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction($object, $floor)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->findBy(array('object'=>$object,'floor'=>$floor));

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'object' =>$object,
        'floor' => $floor

    );
}
/**
 * Creates a new Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="admin_apartment_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("ApartmentBundle:Apartment:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Apartment();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
  //  echo '------------';
 //  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_apartment_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Apartment entity.
 *
 * @param Apartment $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Apartment $entity)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ApartmentType($manager), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_apartment_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/{object}/{floor}", name="admin_apartment_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction($object, $floor)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entityObj = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find($object);
    $entityFloor = $em->getRepository('FloorBundle:Floor')->find($floor);

    $entity = new Apartment();
    $entity->setObject($entityObj);
    $entity->setFloor($entityFloor);
  //  echo 'uuuuuuuuuuuu';
  //  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity);
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
        'floor' =>  $entityFloor->getId(),
        'object' => $entityObj->getId()
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_apartment_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Apartment entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="admin_apartment_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Apartment entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Apartment entity.
*
* @param Apartment $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Apartment $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ApartmentType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_apartment_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_apartment_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("ApartmentBundle:Apartment:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Apartment entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_apartment_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Deletes a Apartment entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_apartment_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Apartment entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_apartment'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Apartment entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin_apartment_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

So look the apartment index method indexAction. There I get the id of the url object (id of the object - building) and floor (id of the floor) and then get all the apartments.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('ApartmentBundle:Apartment')->findBy(array('object'=>$object,'floor'=>$floor));
```

For some reason, I don't understand why when you try to open the edit action with the generated url editAction($id), it tries to open again the index.

I do understand that they do match by parameters see the example:

http://localhost:8000/admin/apartment/59/10
http://localhost:8000/admin/apartment/edit/1

What is the best solution for this? I need to input more parameters in the edit or?

Comment: Because it match your first route, you should move edit action up, or add requirements to other routes like `requirements={"object" = "\d+"}`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Or to add also one parameter more in the edit route maybe the requirements is better.

Comment: It works fine can you place it like answer with little more description to be more useful for others when they visit the post and I can match it like a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it upper before the index for simple solution. Or you can add requirements. See more in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html